# Laravel: signed Url without appending data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Is there any way to create a [signed URL](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#signed-urls) in Laravel(9.x) without appending the data as GET-parameter to the URL?

E.G.:

```
echo \URL::signedRoute('testpage', ['email' => 'test@test.com']);
```

results into:

```
http://localhost:8000/testpage?email=test%40test.com&signature=c845052c0301980b75ad02d6d151e3ea8275f1e1b977c148aa7f423505d99470
```

What I want to achieve (URL with only signature as parameter):

```
http://localhost:8000/testpage?signature=c845052c0301980b75ad02d6d151e3ea8275f1e1b977c148aa7f423505d99470
```

Some users might think it's weird to see their clear e-mail-address in a URL, and it could be a privacy issue.

Comment: The point of the signature is so that if any part of the url is altered it is invalidated. The email address is part of that signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signature is a hash not an encryption, you can't extract data from it, just compare it to the content.

You can either use their ID, wouldn't make much sense to them

```
echo \URL::signedRoute('testpage', ['subject' => $user->id]);
```

or encode the data

```
echo \URL::signedRoute('testpage', ['email' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::encryptString('test@test.com')]);
```

and decrypt it when needed

```
$email = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::decryptString($email);
```

But if you go with encryption, the signature is no longer needed.

Comment: Good idea with encoding the data for that function! Couldn't I also use `\Crypt::encryptString(json_encode(['page' => 'testpage', 'email' => 'test@test.com']))` and append it as the only GET-Parameter (`localhost:8000/testpage?hash=`)? And then decrypt it and check it on the specific page? Do you have something in your mind, which speaks against that practice? What is the better variant in general?

Comment: @klediooo do what suits you. hiding the name of the variable is not that important, in my opinion, if non encrypted values are not accepted.